# MySQL query Join tables with WHERE including matches and non matches

Tags: php, mysql, join, where-clause

The following query matches the ID of electors with the corresponding elector from voting intentions looks for certain criteria.

```
    "   FROM electors,voting_intention 
WHERE electors.ID = voting_intention.elector 
AND electors.telephone > 0 
AND electors.postal_vote != 1 
AND (mosaic IN ('E1','E2','E3') 
OR (voting_intention.pledge IN ('C','P') 
AND  voting_intention.election != '2012-07-05'))  "
```

The problem is with the line `AND (mosaic IN ('E1','E2','E3')` as we need to pick up this information even if there is not a match between electors.ID and voting_intention.elector as this info is in the elector table.

Would the way to do that be to put this line first in the WHERE equation.

Comment: Looks like we are doing your hole project today

Comment: if you are performing INNER JOIN then how it is impacting your result.

Comment: Make certain that you are parenthesizing the ands and ors correctly. I think as it stands now there is an ambiguity in the logic that may be causing your unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it!

```
FROM electors e
FULL OUTER JOIN votin_intention i
   ON e.ID=i.elector
WHERE electors.telephone > 0  
AND electors.postal_vote != 1  
AND (mosaic IN ('E1','E2','E3')  
OR (voting_intention.pledge IN ('C','P')  
AND  voting_intention.election != '2012-07-05'))  "
```

Comment: Would this do it FROM electors,voting_intention WHERE electors.telephone > 0 AND electors.postal_vote != 1 AND (electors.mosaic IN ('E1','E2','E3') OR (electors.ID = voting_intention.elector AND voting_intention.pledge IN ('C','P') AND  voting_intention.election_date != '2012-07-05'))

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is a left outer join to pick all records not just those with a full join

```
WHERE electors.ID(+) = voting_intention.elector
```

Something like that...(untested)

Answer (score 0):

WOULD THIS DO IT:::

```
FROM electors,voting_intention WHERE electors.telephone > 0 AND electors.postal_vote != 1 AND (electors.mosaic IN ('E1','E2','E3') OR (electors.ID = voting_intention.elector AND voting_intention.pledge IN ('C','P') AND  voting_intention.election_date != '2012-07-05'))
```